# Play audio via earpiece is possible?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, avaudioplayer

Is it possible to switch sound output from built-in speaker/headphones to the earpiece? Standard Voice Memos app can do that for playing recoded audio notes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this question

[iPhone AudioSession properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329345/iphone-audiosession-properties/4869414#4869414)