# VOIP dialler tone for outgoing call iOS webrtc

Tags: ios, voip, webrtc

I am working on VOIP in iOS using `webrtc`.

How to produce dialer tone for outgoing call ,  i.e. how to produce the ringer sound in ear speaker till the outgoing call connected?

Answer (score 1):

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/TEST.aif", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];
AVAudioPlayer * keepAwakePlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];

UInt32 doSetProperty = TRUE;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error: nil];   AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryMixWithOthers, sizeof(doSetProperty), &doSetProperty);        
keepAwakePlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;
   [keepAwakePlayer play];
```

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ways to do that.

1. Play a recorded audio file.
2. Create a sound wave on demand.
   AFAIK, telephones play a sine wave of the musical note A, which is
   440 Hz. You can create the wave and add a lot of zeros at the end to
   add the silence. Then play it on loop until the call is answered.

Comment: Me too thinking of that. But i want to know how to play it in ear speaker.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329345/iphone-audiosession-properties/4869414#4869414

Answer (score 0):

Based on Maverick's answer.This will play ringtone in ear speaker like in a phone call (works on iOS 10.3).

```
NSError *av_error = nil;
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/digitalphone.caf", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];
av_Player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&av_error];
NSError *sesionError = nil;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord withOptions:kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute error:&sesionError];
av_Player.numberOfLoops = -1;
[av_Player play];
```